# Zend Framework: How to unset a key in Zend_Registry?

Tags: php, zend-framework, registry, config

I am testing my Zend Framework application and would like to test that something happens when a particular key is not set in the registry. This is the function that I am testing:

```
protected function getDomainFromConfig() {
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    if (!isset($config->domain)) {
        throw new Exception('Please make sure you have "domain" set in your config file and your config file is being set in the Zend_Registry.');
    }
    return $config->domain;
}
```

How can I unset a key in the registry? I tried this, but it did not work:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
$config->__unset('domain');
```

**Update:** What I really want to know is how should I test that my method throws an exception when the "domain" key in the config file is not set.

Comment: I think you might find your answer here: [http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2752](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2752)

Comment: If you follow the advice given in my answer, this should have let you test that the exception is thrown. Otherwise, perhaps you would like to accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only real way to change the value of the config object would be to dump it to a variable, unset the item in question, ask the registry to delete the key for config, and then reset it.

```
<?php
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$config = $registry->get('config');
unset($config->domain);
$registry->offsetUnset('config');
$registry->set('config', $config);
?>
```

However, for this to work you would have to have set the Zend_Config object to editable before it is set into the registry the first time.

You should consider that it is not best practice to edit the registry in this way. In particular, the Zend_Config object is designed to be static once it is instantiated originally.

I hope I have understood your problem well enough!

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore, so I haven't had a chance to verify your answer, so I am accepting it based on number of user votes.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'config' is actually `Zend_Config`, then by default it's read-only.
`Zend_Config` constructor's optional second parameter is boolean `$allowModifications`, by default set to `false`.

You probably create `Zend_Config_Ini` in `bootstrap.php` with

```
new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/config/app.ini', 
                    APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT)
```

append `$allowModifications` param:

```
new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/config/app.ini', 
                    APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT, 
                    true)
```

Comment: That's exactly the error message I am getting: Zend_Registry is read-only. I need a way to fake it. Maybe there is a different way to do it, rather than actually "unsetting" it.

Comment: Zend_Registry or Zend_Config?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
unset($config->domain);
```

And then re-register `$registry->config` with the modified `Zend_Config` class. Note that, as vartec said, you'll have to instantiate your `Zend_Config` instance as editable:

```
$config = new Zend_Config('filename', true);
```

The `__unset` method you're trying to call is a [magic method](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) that is called when you use `unset` on the instance.

Comment: unset($config->domain) calls $config->__unset('domain'), so it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing you are trying to delete a value in the $config, where $config is stored in Zend_Registry before deletion. so if deleting the value does not affect the stored $config value in Zend_Registry, I assume that by calling Zend_Registry::get() you are having the value of $config and not a reference to the $config in Zend_Registry. so when you change something in the copied $config, it will not affect the stored one. I suggest you first change the $config, and then overwrite the $config in the registry, by setting the $config in Zend_Registry again.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to accomplish what the title asks, to unset a Zend_Registry key:

```
class My_Registry extends Zend_Registry
{
    /**
     *
     * @param type $index
     */
    public static function delete($index)
    {
        $instance = self::getInstance();

        if ($instance->offsetExists($index)) {
            $instance->offsetUnset($index);
        }
    }
}
```

Call by: `My_Registry::delete('key')`